# Shopify Limit Tagged Products

Tags: shopify

I'm currently working on a Shopify theme, I have a list of all products, I've filtered them to only show anything with the following tag 'Neoprene' - how do I not limit the tagged product to only show 4?

Any help would be grateful!

```
<main class="wrapper">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid__item">
      <div class="large--one-whole">
      {% for product in collections.all.products limit: 9999 %}
        {% if product.tags contains 'Neoprene' %}
        <div class="landing-product grid__item large--one-quarter medium--one-quarter small--one-half">
          <a href="{{ product.url }}" class="img">
            {% for image in product.images %}
              <span class="grid-link__image-centered">
                <img src="{{ product.featured_image.src | img_url: 'grande' }}" alt="{{ product.featured_image.alt | escape }}">
              </span>
            {% endfor %}
          </a>
          <a href="{{ product.url }}" class="title">
            {{ product.title }}
          </a>
          <a href="{{ product.url }}" class="price">
            {{ product.price | money }}
          </a>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<main class="wrapper">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid__item">
      <div class="large--one-whole">
      {% assign a = 0 %}
      {% for product in collections.all.products limit: 9999 %}
        {% if a == 4 %}
            {% break %}
        {% else %}        
          {% if product.tags contains 'Neoprene' %}
          {% assign a = a | plus : 1 %}
          <div class="landing-product grid__item large--one-quarter medium--one-quarter small--one-half">
            <a href="{{ product.url }}" class="img">
              {% for image in product.images %}
                <span class="grid-link__image-centered">
                  <img src="{{ product.featured_image.src | img_url: 'grande' }}" alt="{{ product.featured_image.alt | escape }}">
                </span>
              {% endfor %}
            </a>
            <a href="{{ product.url }}" class="title">
              {{ product.title }}
            </a>
            <a href="{{ product.url }}" class="price">
              {{ product.price | money }}
            </a>
          </div>
          {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```